# How to consume asp.net web service in SharePoint site?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

I have asp.net web service application created in VS 2010. I created this web service using ASP.NET Web Service Application template in VS 2010. My InfoPath form consumes my webservice. However to fill out my IP form, I first have to make sure I run my web service, otherwise I get errors like cannot connect to the webservice.

How can I make sure my web services are properly deployed to my SharePoint site that hosts infoPath form services? Please let me know the necessary steps. If my web services are deployed to my SharePoint site then there's no need to manually run my asp.net web service in the browser everytime I need to fill out the form. Thanks.

[image]
Here's the error message I got when I tried to browse my custom web service deployed to layouts folder:

```
http://abcd/_layouts/WebServiceDemo/MyCustomWebService.asmx
```

I couldn't find relevant message in 14-->LOGS. Any idea what's causing this? Thanks.
My own analysis: Please visit the web.config inside LAYOUTS folder and set Customerros to Off to get more meaningful error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Googled "How to consume asp.net web service in SharePoint site".

The third hit was [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET (ASMX) Web Service in SharePoint 2010](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx). The post shows how to create, deploy and consume the service.

Comment: Thanks. I got that article as well. I want to know if there are any other ways to do it.What's the best practice, recommendations, precautions that needs to take care of while doing so. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: If you want the official recommendation from Microsoft look at their walkthough (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx). The walkthrough I linked in my answer (which I wrote) provides and alternate method that I feel is simpler and easier to understand. Either way, the recommended way to deploy a web service to SharePoint is though a solution package as demonstrated in both walkthroughs.

Comment: Hi Rob, my apologies! I didn't realize that I was talking to the author of the article himself. :)Yes I did also visit the MS MSDN article which is too complicated for me and seen that few people couldn't get it working. Yours is terse. I once messed up deploying ti 14 hive so want to be very catious this time. Thanks again. Will try it out in test env. and will def follow up with you. Thanks again for your help and thanks to this platform- I could discuss tech stuff with experts. :)

Comment: Wasn't trying to sound self important. Just wanted you to know that the opinions expressed in the blog post were mine.

Comment: Oh, and everyone who has deployed something to the SharePoint system folders (12/14 hive) has messed things up. For most of us it's been more that once. The lessons are usually pretty tough but that's how we learn

Comment: Hi Rob, sorry for the late response. Got into other issues. Finally got time to fiddle with your example. I was following it however I didn't find "In the Add Reference dialog, select the .NET tab, select System.Web.Services, and click OK. 
". I couldn't find that dll in the windows. How can I get it? Once I get it, your example seems to be pretty straight forward. My concern is where do I add <connectionStrings/>. With asp.net web service application, comes web.config. But with your eg., where would I add it? Please kindly let me know. TIA.

Comment: The System.Web.Services assembly is part of the .NET Framework. Did you create a SharePoint project? If you did it has to be there. The issue of where to store connection strings is out of the scope of this topic. Do a search for "where to store connection strings in a sharepoint project" and you'll find some guidance.

Comment: Yes, I did create a SharePoint Project. And I m using .net framework 3.5. I will def. try finding out where to store connection strings in SharePoint project. I found the System.Web.Services in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727. However its not present in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5. That's why on creating asp.net web service application, its referencing the one in v2.0. Will it be ok if I reference the one in v2.0? TIA.

Comment: If you look at my blog post you see that the version number of the System.Web.Services assembly is 2.0.0.0 and the runtime is 2.0.50727. When adding references to .NET Framework assemblies, use the .NET tab rather than browsing. Visual Studio knows which assemblies are the correct ones to use for the .NET Framework version you are targeting.

Comment: When adding references to .NET Framework assemblies, use the .NET tab rather than browsing.--This is what I did. And I will paste the screenshot in my above post. Please let me know how can I fix this issue.

Comment: After the assemblies have finished loading in the .NET tab, click the Component Name header to sort them alphabetically then look again. If System.Web.Services is not there you have some sort of configuration issue with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Rob.I was able to locate after following your last post. I was successfully able to deploy the web service to _Layouts folder. But when I hit this link http://abcd/_layouts/WebServiceDemo/MyCustomWebService.asmx, I get Server Error in '/' Application. I m not sure what's causing it. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: nvm. I figured out the solution. I set Customerrors to Off in the web.config inside the LAYOUTS folder. It showed me the parse error with the strong name of the assembly. My strong name ran into next line so I made sure its all in one one. Got the same result as your solution. Thanks a lot Rob for your help/time. I need to go a long way to figure out where to add connectionstrings etc etc. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rob, sorry to bother you again. But I need to know one thing- I need to consume my custom web service in InfoPath form. When I try to consume from the SharePoint server, it doesn't throw error. But when I try to create InfoPath form from outside SharePOint server(because now I can easily use my custom ws deployed in _layouts folder), its saying "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: SELECT permission denied on object 'myDB', database 'myTable', schema 'dbo'.". I want to know under what a/c does web service run to get to SQL db? TIA.